# Django substitute username field

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to substitute the default username field of the User model when it's extended via AbstractUser?

If I try with:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'my_custom_field'
```

in my extended model, I get this error:

> TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
>   when I syncdb and create the superuser.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give us a better context?

Comment: Okay, lets see. 
I have to add some fields to the default User model i.e. to extend it so I'm using AbstractUser model as a parent to my custom model which defines the additional fields. In my occasion is just one - 'pin' which is DecimalField. 

So the problem is that I want to use the 'pin' field in the place of the username i.e. to substitute the default username field with my pin field.

I hope I gave you a better context understanding.

Comment: Instead of describing it, you should show your actual model.

Comment: Not much of a help...
`class MyUser(AbstractUser):
 pin = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 8)

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'pin'`

Comment: Actually, it is helpful: [The field _must_ be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition).](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD)

Comment: Actually, I made it. 
But the problem is with the creation. The create_superuser takes username, email and password where the last two can be optional (None).

I have to use the pin instead of the username. But when I define my model as that above. The username is skipped in the syncdb but the create_superuser() is waiting to be passed...